# C++ Standards Committee "reflector" mailing lists

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

I have from time to time heard mention of a mailing list or lists called "reflector(s)" where members of the C++ Standards Committee discuss issues related to their work on C++ standardization.

Are these mailing lists available for public reading? If so, could someone point me to them? If not, what is the rationale for them being closed? I for one would find it very useful to be able to read these discussions - I think they would provide great insights into the rationales behind the various decisions made by the Committee.

Comment: To those who voted the question closed because it's off-topic: could you please recommend a better forum to ask this question, whether it's another Stack Exchange site or something else?

Comment: i don't understand why this is voted as offtopic.

Comment: The committee has a web site where they publish their public material http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/ The mailing list seems to be members only.

Comment: I voted to move it to programmers.stackexchange, since it doesn't contain code, but since that didn't happen I'm reopening here. It ought to be somewhere rather than nowhere.

Comment: I'm so _not_ getting the point of splitting SO into dozens of little pieces.

Comment: The public reflectors are currently here: https://lists.isocpp.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi

Comment: @ergosys welcome to the club. Also note that many of the most useful old questions here would no longer be allowed in any stackexchange site. There was a huge fight within the main SO people maybe 8 or 9 years ago about direction. This was the winner

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just discovered the following four Google Groups, opened a few days ago:

- https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/group/lang-discussion/about
- https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/group/lang-proposals/about
- https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/group/lib-discussion/about
- https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/group/lib-proposals/about

It's not immediately clear whether these are official, though the owner's email is "admin@isocpp.org", so they may well be.

**UPDATE**: It appears they are official. From [boost-dev](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/C-Standards-Committee-membership-for-Boost-td4623431.html):

> It's an initiative led by Herb Sutter.
>
> He proposes that the
>   committee moves to publically readable (but not writable) discussion
>   groups for the reflector and also that we replace comp.std.c++ by new
>   public read/write groups (which are the ones you linked).

I think that is great news!

---

**UPDATE**: The 'lang' and 'lib' groups have been merged into one. The new groups can be found here:

- https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/groups/dir

Comment: These groups will be dying soon. Google Groups won't be supporting groups with high populations. (As in, no one can post but those white-listed, and there's a limit.)

Comment: @Narfanar: The committee is aware, and will be migrating the groups to mailman over the next few months.

Answer (score 11):

There are a number of mailing lists referred to as the "reflector", indeed: broken down by topics for the core language, the library, extensions, and announcements (I'm not sure if there are others). However, the committee's mailing lists are for members of the committee only. I think that the standards organizations mandate that these lists can only be entered by committee members. It is reasonably simple to become a member, though: become a member of a national body (ANSI, DIN, BSI, etc.) and you are in. Depending on which of the national bodies you go to, they may mandate that you pay, show up at meetings, or both. It is fun to go to the meetings as well: the upcoming one is just next week in Kona, Hawaii. Meeting details of the ANSI and ISO meetings (held jointly) are available from the [committee's Web site](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/).

That said, whether the mailing lists are that useful is a different matter. Some issues get beaten to death over there while others don't really show up on the mailing list at all but are only discussed at the meetings. Realistically, this is where the decisions are made anyway. I think it is more useful to read the proposals (also available from the site above) and/or go to the meetings to understand the rationale. At the first meeting I went to I just showed up because I wanted to meet people in person who I met only online before (I new that several of the other moderators of comp.lang.c++.moderated went to this meeting). I found it rather enlightening and went to many meetings since (some paid by my employer, some paid on my own, sometimes officially on a delegation, sometimes not).

Comment: Nice to know that it is relatively easy to become a member, but I still wish the work of the committee was more transparent.

Answer (score 2):

The public mailing lists are here now: https://lists.isocpp.org